# Partition function $\mathrm{tr} e^{-\beta H}$ for non-trace-class operator

Tags: hilbert-space, operators, mathematical-physics, partition-function, trace

For Hamiltonian $H$, the partition function is defined as
$$Z=\mathrm{tr} e^{-\beta H}.$$

However, consider a free particle $H = -\Delta$ in $\mathbb R^1$. In this case, the operator $e^{-\beta H}$ is not trace-class, and therefore the partition function is not defined. I think we can come up with many other examples of Hamiltonians such that $e^{-\beta H}$ is not trace-class.

How should we deal with this situation? Is there any work done by mathematical physicist regarding this matter? (I have a mathematical background on measure theory, functional analysis, etc.)

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/457369

Comment: @NiharKarve In that post, one arbitrary confines the system inside the box. Is there any more intrinsic or rigorous approach?

Comment: KMS formalism...